# Create xml reports in Google Tests in main()

Tags: c++, xml, unit-testing, googletest

Is it possible to make GoogleTest output an xml file by asking it to, in `main()` ?

I know I can change the system environment variables (does anybody actually do that ?), or use a command line argument

> --gtest_output="xml:_path_to_output_file_".

What I would like to do is have my program automatically generate the xml, every time, using a file name based on the project name. And of course - it would not happen on my computer...

I looked in InitGoogleTest, but I can't see anything I can touch.

(I would like to write actual code, not run my program in a postbuild).

Are there any options for this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply assign `GTEST_FLAG(output) = "xml:_path_to_output_file_";`. If you do that before invoking `InitGoogleTest`, it will act as a default. If you do that after invoking `InitGoogleTest`, it will override any `--gtest_output` value you provide in the command line.